# Mono FastCGI Server - Applications don't work below root

Tags: mono, fastcgi, xsp

Okay, I cannot figure this out.  I have a test MVC app (razoronmono).  I just compiled mono from master today, as well as xsp.  I also compiled nginx today.  I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 minimal.

This works:
http://coh2.us.to/razoronmono/

This doesn't:
http://coh2.us.to/apps/razoronmono/

All code in the subdirectories is the same...

applications="/:/srv/www,/razoronmono:/srv/www/razoronmono,/apps/razoronmono:/srv/www/apps/razoronmono"

nginx config:
        location / {

```
    }
    location /razoronmono {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index /;
    }

    location /apps/razoronmono {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index /;
    }
    location ~ \.(aspx|asmx|ashx|asax|ascx|soap|rem|axd|cs|config|dll)$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException Failed to map path
>   '/apps/_ViewStart.cshtml'
>
> Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
>
> Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or
>   object): System.Web. Exception stack trace: at
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath (System.String virtualPath,
>   System.String baseVirtualDir, Boolean allowCrossAppMapping) [0x001a4]
>   in /usr/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpRequest.cs:1572
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath (System.String virtualPath)
>   [0x0000d] in
>   /usr/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpRequest.cs:1526 at
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath (System.String
>   virtualPath) [0x00042] in
>   /usr/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Hosting/HostingEnvironment.cs:156
>   at System.Web.Hosting.DefaultVirtualPathProvider.FileExists
>   (System.String virtualPath) [0x00016] in
>   /usr/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Hosting/DefaultVirtualPathProvider.cs:68
>   at System.Web.WebPages.FileExistenceCache.FileExists (System.String
>   virtualPath) [0x00000] in :0 at
>   System.Web.WebPages.VirtualPathFactoryManager.PageExistsInVPP
>   (System.String virtualPath, Boolean useCache) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Web.WebPages.VirtualPathFactoryManager.PageExists
>   (System.String virtualPath, Boolean useCache) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.FileExists
>   (System.String path, Boolean useCache) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.GetStartPage
>   (System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRenderingBase page, System.String
>   fileName, IEnumerable`1 supportedExtensions) [0x00000] in <filename
>   unknown>:0 at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView
>   (System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext viewContext, System.IO.TextWriter writer,
>   System.Object instance) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 at
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render
>   (System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext viewContext, System.IO.TextWriter writer)
>   [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult
>   (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context) [0x00000] in <filename
>   unknown>:0 at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult
>   (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext,
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x00000] in <filename
>   unknown>:0 at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19
>   () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter
>   (IResultFilter filter, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext
>   preContext, System.Func`1 continuation) [0x00000] in :0

Answer (score 1):

The xsp repo is undergoing these days severe refactorings due to Google Summer of Code. These refactorings could likely cause regressions. Then:

1. Please compile xsp tag 3.0.10 instead of master, to see if the problem goes away.
2. If it does, please file a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ (and add "[regression]" in the summary) and contact @minibill in irc://irc.gnome.org/monodevelop to give him a heads up about the problem he might have introduced.
3. If the problem doesn't go away, file the bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/.

Comment: There is no tag 3.0.10.  I have compiled tag 3.0.11 and it's what I'm currently using but unfortunately it doesn't resolve the error.

Comment: I've added the bug, hopefully correctly, I've never used Bugzilla before: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13768

Comment: if it doesn't resolve the error then it is NOT a regression, so please remove the word "regression" from your bug's summary

Comment: Sorry. I've fixed the summary description.

Comment: cool; also: the summary still doesn't describe the bug well. What "does not work mean"? Please state something like "website only works at the root folder of the domain"